# confused by notation in my computer vision book

Tags: linear-algebra

My book, Szeliski *Computer Vision Algorithms and Applications* says that:

$$
x' = [R t] \, \bar{x}
$$

and says that

$$
x' = Rx + t
$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iupeU.jpg

Can someone explain what $[R t]$ means, and what $\bar{x}$ means?

It says that $R$ is the $2\times 2$ rotation matrix, and $t$ is the translation.

I can't put my mind around how

$$
Rx + t = [R t] \, \bar{x}
$$

is $[R t]$ a legal notation in linear algebra/multidimensional calculus?

Can I make a matrix 
$$
U = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\ 
3 & 4
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
and a vector $v = (1, 2)$ and make a construct $G = [U v]$? 
I have never seen this kind of construct in my life.

I understand it's a notation concern and it may be difficult to help me,
but if it's at all possible to explain what [Matrix vector] notation means if it's legal, i'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you are asking about notation, it's really difficult to help when it's not formatted correctly. Please read the following page and edit your question appropriately: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The problem is that as it stand it is unanswerable, and will probably be closed. Taking the time to format everything avoids that.

Comment: Or, if you can't format, take a picture!

Comment: I have added the picture.

Comment: Don't see the picture. @Dmitry

Comment: its a link, i wasn't sure if i should hard include it.

Comment: I'd edit the image to only include the part of the page you are referring to. Help people help you.

Comment: It is possible to combine the linear transformation represented by $R$ with a translation vector represented by $t$ in a way that allows both actions to be represented by a single matrix multiplication.  This is often done in 3D software applications, where the resulting matrix becomes a $4\times 4$ representation.  I would guess that something similar here explains the notation you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like a notation to keep the translation part (affine map!) in an extra column.

$\bar{x}$ seems to be the homogenous version of vector $x$:

$$
\bar{x} = 
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x_1 \\ 
x_2 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

$2\times 3$ Notation:
$$
x' =
[ R t] \, \bar{x}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
R_{11} & R_{12} & t_1 \\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & t_2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x_1 \\ 
x_2 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
R_{11} x_1 + R_{12} x_2 + t_1 \\ 
R_{21} x_1 + R_{22} x_2 + t_2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
R x + t 
\in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

$3\times 3$ Notation:
$$
\bar{x}' =
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
R & t \\
0^T & 1
\end{matrix}
\right] 
\, 
\bar{x}
=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
R_{11} & R_{12} & t_1 \\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & t_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
x_1 \\ 
x_2 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
R_{11} x_1 + R_{12} x_2 + t_1 \\ 
R_{21} x_1 + R_{22} x_2 + t_2 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
R x + t \\ 
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\in \mathbb{R}^3
$$

Going from $2\times 2$ to $2\times 3$ matrices (extra column) allows to represent the translation transformations as well.

The idea behind homogenous cooordinates is to add an extra dimension (extra column and extra row) which allows to represent all transformations as matrices *and* the composition of several transformations as matrix products.

You can chain two $3\times 3$ matrices by matrix multiplication, but not two
$2\times 3$ matrices.
See also the slight uglyness with $2\times 3$ notation that it is $[R t] \bar{x}$ and not $[R t] x$ because a 3D vector is required.

In case of 2D vectors and $2\times 2$ matrices you end up with 3D vectors and $3\times 3$ matrices. The third component of the vectors is usually normalized to $1$. See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) for some examples.

OpenGL is an example of a 3D graphics library / hardware using $4\times 4$ matrices.

Comment: The $2\times 3$ version $[R t]$ is a matrix augmented by a vector. The $3\times 3$ version is the one with homogenous coordinates. This example with rotation and translation does not show the advantage of homogenous coordinates. That will come if you want to go to $x'' = A x'$ for whatever transformation $A$ and then try to figure out how the combined transformation $x'' = A\circ [R t] x$ looks like.